Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null [vite build]
When I run the build of my Vite project I have this error
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
migrating from CRA to vite
I have tried to place some keys on vite.config.js
my vite config looks like this.
I don't know if forgot something
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.xlsx'],
  plugins: [],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [inject({ Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'] })],
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    mainFields: [],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
    },
  },
});

My console:

My built file:

